# Using Rayon into_par_iter().sum() with custom struct

Tags: rust, rayon

I'm trying to get use Rayon::prelude::into_par_iter to sum up a bunch of instances of a struct. I've implemented `std::iter::Sum` for the struct, but am still running into an error. Here is my example code;

```
use std::iter::Sum;

use rayon::prelude::*;

pub struct TestStruct {
    val: f32,
}

impl TestStruct {
    pub fn new(v: f32) -> Self {
        Self { val: v }
    }
}

impl<'a> Sum<&'a Self> for TestStruct {
    fn sum<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = &'a Self>,
    {
        iter.fold(Self { val: 0. }, |a, b| Self {
            val: a.val + b.val,
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let default_val: f32 = 1.1;
    let sum: TestStruct = (0..5).into_par_iter().map(|&default_val| {
        TestStruct::new(default_val)
    })
    .sum();

    println!("{}", sum.val);
}
```

and I am told `the trait 'std::iter::Sum' is not implemented for 'TestStruct'`, but I think I am implementing it. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two small compounded issues. One is that the `std::iter::Sum` is defined as:

```rust
pub trait Sum<A = Self> {
    fn sum<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = A>;
}
```

The `Self` here refers to whatever the struct gets the implementation and the default generic parameter has already been filled in. You don't need to specify it any more if implementing `Sum` for struct itself.

The other is that the `map` closure parameter `default_val`, which is an integer, shadows the previous float one with the same name. Since `TestStruct::new` expects a `f32`, it leads to a type error.

This works:

```rust
impl Sum for TestStruct {
    fn sum<I>(iter: I) -> Self
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = Self>,
    {
        ...
    }
}

fn main() {
    let default_val: f32 = 1.1;
    let sum: TestStruct = (0..5)
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|_| TestStruct::new(default_val))
        .sum();

    println!("{}", sum.val);
}
```